# How to calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(mx)}{1+x^{4}}\,dx$

Tags: integration

How to calculate $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(mx)}{1+x^{4}}\,dx$$
where $m$ is a constant?

Any hint will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried with contour integration?

Comment: look at this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/793301/59379) for the special case $m = 1$.

Comment: Contour integration along a proper chosen half-circle after reducing $\int_0^\infty=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty$. The [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos(mx)%2F(1%2Bx%5E4),+x%3D0..infinity).

Comment: OK，thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

By the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem),
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(mx)}{1+x^4}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}e^{-|m|/\sqrt{2}}\left(\sin\frac{|m|}{\sqrt{2}}+\cos\frac{|m|}{\sqrt{2}}\right).$$