# In computing a complicated complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

***I have revised my method and it turns out consider the half disk is **easier** than consider a wedge. Thanks for the comments and the answer. However I tend to leave my (incorrect) computation here.

Let us try to compute $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x^4+1} \, dx$.

The first step is to acknowledge that $\frac{\cos x}{x^4+1} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{e^{ix}}{x^4+1} + \frac{e^{-ix}}{x^4+1})$ **(1)**

Let us take a look at $\frac{e^{ix}}{x^4+1}$, I think we should compute its value on a wedge-like curve **y**, including only $z= e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}} $ as a pole.

Now apply Residue Theorem, we know that its value is $ \frac{\pi  i}{2} e^{ie^{\frac{\pi i }{4}}} e^{\frac{\pi i }{4}} $

Now, note that on the wedge, the perpendicular part is $-e^{\frac{\pi i }{4}}$ times the value of the straight line, and the value on the arc is 0 as R goes to infinity.

Now we have $(1-e^{\frac{\pi i }{4}})  \frac{e^{ix}}{x^4+1} =   \frac{\pi  i}{2} e^{ie^{\frac{\pi i }{4}}} e^{\frac{\pi i }{4}} $, and adjust this we have $\frac{e^{ix}}{x^4+1}$ = $e^{ie^{\frac{\pi i }{4}}} \frac{\pi/4}{\sin(\pi/4)} $ **(2)**, for the $\frac{e^{-ix}}{x^4+1}$ part I suspect we can compute it in another wedge with negative imaginary part and we will end up with the exact same value, and according to **(1)** we can conclude that the value fir the integral is **(2)**.

Note that since some of the process is extremely tedious I have been deliberately avoid writing everything out, but I would appreciate very much if you point out any mistakes or unclear part.
My main question is that:

1. is this a valid approach?
2. Can there be any easier way?

An additional question is: is there a reliable calculator for improper integral online so I can validify before posting a question? Wolfram Alpha doesn't seem to have such function.

Comment: Does this answer point 2 of your question? [Evaluate the definite integral $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x^4 +1} \ \ dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793227/evaluate-the-definite-integral-int-infty-infty-frac-cosxx4-1) Something is wrong with your approach as the answer should be real, but yours is a complex number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Without complex analysis.*

Write
$$x^4+1=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$$ and use partial fraction decomposition. You will face a linar combination of integrals
$$I_k=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x-k}\,dx$$ No problem for the antiderivative since
$$J_k=\int\frac{\cos(x)}{x-k}\,dx=\int\frac{\cos (k+y)}{y}\,dy=\cos (k)\int\frac{ \cos (y)}{y}\,dy-\sin (k)\int\frac{ \sin (y)}{y}\,dy$$
$$J_k=\cos (k)\,\text{Ci}(y) -\sin (k)\, \text{Si}(y)$$ Now, you will need to work a few complex numbers and you should end with
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos (x)}{x^4+1} \, dx=\frac{ \pi  }{\sqrt{2}}\left(\sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\cos
   \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\,e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$$